# Is keras based on closures in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

While working with keras and tensorflow, I found the following lines of code confusing.

```
w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units),
                                          dtype='float32'),trainable=True)
```

Also, I have seen something like:

```
 Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
```

Therefore, if `Dense(...)` will create the object for me, then how can I follow that with with `(x)`?

Likewise for `w_init` above. How can I say such thing:

```
tf.random_normal_initializer()(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype='float32'),trainable=True)
```

Do we have such thing in python `"ClassName()" followed by "()"` while creating an object such as a layer?

While I was looking into [Closures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Functions) in python, I found that a function can return another function. Hence, is this what really happens in Keras?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Please rewrite the question to be absolute clear what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two totally different ways to define models.

#### Keras

Keras works with the concept of layers. Each line defines a full layer of your network. What you are referring to in specific is keras' functional API. The concept is to combine layers like this:

```py
inp = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = Conv2D((6,6), strides=(1,1), activation='relu')(inp)
# ... etc ...
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)


model = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[x])
```

This way you've created a full CNN in just a few lines. Note that you **never** had to manually input the shape of the weight vectors or the operations that are performed. These are inferred automatically by keras.

Now, this just needs to be *compiled* through `model.compile(...)` and then you can train it through `model.fit(...)`.

#### Tensorflow

On the other hand TensorFlow is a bit more low-level. This means that you have do define the variables and operations by hand. So in order to write a fully-connected layer you'd have to do the following:

```py
# Input placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10))

# Convolution layer
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([6, 6, 1, 32], stddev=0.1)) 
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [32]))
z1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x_2d, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + b1 
c1 = tf.nn.relu(z1)

# ... etc ...

# Flatten
flat = tf.reshape(p2, [-1, ...]) # need to calculate the ... by ourselves

# Dense
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([..., 10], stddev=0.1))  # same size as before
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [10]))
fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(flat, W3) + b3)
```

Two things to note here. There is no explicit definition of a `model` here and this has to be trained through a `tf.Session` with a `feed_dict` feeding the data to the placeholders. If you're interested you'll find several guides online.

#### Closing notes...

TensorFlow has a much friendlier and easier way to define and train models through **eager execution**, which will be default in TF 2.0! So the code you posted is in a sense the *old way* of doing things in tensorflow. It's worth taking a look into TF 2.0, which actually recommends doing things the keras way!

---

Edit (after comment by OP):

No a layer is **not a clojure**. A keras layer is a class that implements a `__call__` method which also makes it callable. The way they did it was so that it is a wrapper to the `call` method that users typically write.

You can take a look at the implementation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L376)

Basically how this works is:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.p = param
    def call(self, x):
        print(x)
```

If you try to write `c = MyClass(1)(3)`, you'll get a TypeError saying that MyClass is not callable. But if you write it like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.p = param
    def __call__(self, x):
        print(x)
```

It works now. Essentially keras does it like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.p = param
    def call(self, x):
        print(x)
    def __call__(self, x):
        self.call(x)
```

So that when you write your own layer you can implement your own `call` method and the `__call__` method that wraps your one will get inherited from keras' base Layer class.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, this is not what I am asking for at a first hand. What I am referring to is more into how objects are truly created in python with the way I mentioned in the question. So I'm not asking how to build models in tensorflow or keras and which one is better and what is the new to create layers, and so on...

Comment: can you please explain what people mean: a layer i callable in keras?

Comment: @I.A you can think of a callable as a function. So `Dense(...)` returns a function and that function takes some kind of input, so `Dense(...)(x)` is basically (1) creating a function (2) calling that function at the same time.

Comment: @I.A I seem to have misunderstood your question. I edited my answer to explain the best I could how keras layers work.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the syntax, I would say that `Dense()` returns a function (or more accurately a **callable**). Similarly `w_init` is a callable as well.